# visual studio XAML designer not loading

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I'm developing Windows phone apps on my Mac Book Pro Retina (late 2013) on a virtual machine using Parallels 9. I have Visual Studio 2012 and Windows phone 8 SDK installed and everything works fine writing code and testing it on my Lumia phone. The problem is that the XAML designer doesn't load i.e. I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException The document failed to open.

    at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.DesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)

    at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
```

Next to this error message, which is displayed instead of the designer, there's a button to reload the designer. But when I press it, it takes forever and gets no results.

I have posted my question in the Microsoft [forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/53caba87-6053-458c-bc1f-77181d99e3c7/visual-studio-xaml-designer-not-loading?forum=wptools) but it seems like a ghost town down there.

Comment: Would probably need to see your xaml to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the project? Sometimes, this helps.

Comment: the exact same error is shown on every project and page I open, even when I open a new project template, this error pops up, so it can't be code-related

Comment: @MartinTausch rebuilding the project didn't help either...

Comment: Have you ran the updates to VisualStudio 2012 (not windows updates, VS updates) and have it up to the most recent version?

Comment: @ChrisW. yes, I have downloaded the most recent SDK and update 3 of visual studio and have them installed

Comment: I'd suggest posting your issue on Microsoft Connect, which is a bug/issue reporting web site for products like Visual Studio. http://connect.microsoft.com/

Answer (score 12):

**Steps:**

1. close all visual studio instances
2. browse to C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
3. rename or remove "ComponentModelCache"
4. restart Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

I also got an infinitely loading Designer. I solved it by deleting the UserControl and recreating it via source control.